# How to refer my new column to existing one

Tags: sql

I have face trouble to create the new field of 'doc' and to check it with an existing column of 'doj' to ensure that doc>doj.

```
alter table data add doc date add constraint chk_date check (doc>doj);
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: Do it in two steps. Add column first, then add check constraint.

Comment: I have tried but it shows error "invalid alter table option"

Comment: Show us that attempt too. And remove the tag for the dbms not used.

Comment: BTW, data is a very odd table name. Do you have tables where you don't store any data?

Comment: thanks, @jarlh for your help. I got output when by using individual alter statement.

Comment: `doc date` is not a valid column name.

Answer (score 0):

These works fine

```
CREATE TABLE [DATA](DOJ DATE);
--Add the second column
ALTER TABLE [DATA]
ADD DOC DATE;
--Add constraint 
ALTER TABLE [DATA]
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_date CHECK(doc > doj);
```